# Keras: How to use fit_generator with multiple outputs of different type

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

In a Keras model with the Functional API I need to call fit_generator to train on augmented images data using an ImageDataGenerator.
The problem is my model has two outputs: the mask I'm trying to predict and a binary value.
I obviously only want to augment the input and the mask output and not the binary value.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The example below might be self-explanatory!
The 'dummy' model takes 1 input (image) and it outputs 2 values. The model computes the MSE for each output.

```
x = Convolution2D(8, 5, 5, subsample=(1, 1))(image_input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(50, W_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

output1 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output1')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output2')(x)

model = Model(input=image_input, output=[output1, output2])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'output1': 'mean_squared_error', 'output2': 'mean_squared_error'})
```

The function below generates batches to feed the model during training. It takes the training data `x` and the label `y` where y=[y1, y2]

```
def batch_generator(x, y, batch_size, is_train):
    sample_idx = 0
    while True:
       X = np.zeros((batch_size, input_height, input_width, n_channels), dtype='float32')
       y1 = np.zeros((batch_size, mask_height, mask_width), dtype='float32')
       y2 = np.zeros((batch_size, 1), dtype='float32')

       # fill up the batch
       for row in range(batch_sz):
           image = x[sample_idx]
           mask = y[0][sample_idx]
           binary_value = y[1][sample_idx]
           # transform/preprocess image
           image = cv2.resize(image, (input_width, input_height))
           if is_train:
               image, mask = my_data_augmentation_function(image, mask)
           X_batch[row, ;, :, :] = image
           y1_batch[row, :, :] = mask
           y2_batch[row, 0] = binary_value
           sample_idx += 1

       # Normalize inputs
       X_batch = X_batch/255.
       yield(X_batch, {'output1': y1_batch, 'output2': y2_batch} ))
```

Finally, we call the fit_generator()

```
model.fit_generator(batch_generator(X_train, y_train, batch_size, is_train=1))
```

Comment: what goes in ....transform images
        ....generate batch batch of size: batch_size . in your answer?

Comment: I edited the answer to add a few more details. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JMarc how can you merge this generator with the ```ImageDataGenerator``` so that it does all the preprocessing on the Rank-4 image matrix but the out from this is fed into a ```new_generator()``` to map value of image to the ```y=[y1,y2]``` to use for training and validtion?

Answer (score 13):

If you have separated both mask and binary value you can try something like this:

```
generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=5.,
                                width_shift_range=0.1, 
                                height_shift_range=0.1, 
                                horizontal_flip=True,  
                                vertical_flip=True)

def generate_data_generator(generator, X, Y1, Y2):
    genX = generator.flow(X, seed=7)
    genY1 = generator.flow(Y1, seed=7)
    while True:
            Xi = genX.next()
            Yi1 = genY1.next()
            Yi2 = function(Y2)
            yield Xi, [Yi1, Yi2]
```

So, you use the same generator for both input and mask **with the same seed** to define the same operation. You may change the binary value or not depending on your needs (Y2). Then, you call the fit_generator():

```
model.fit_generator(generate_data_generator(generator, X, Y1, Y2),
                epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: what do you mean by separate mask and binary value?

Comment: @Jose I have a similar problem and I have ```Y1=df[:,'label_1'].values``` and ```y2=df[:,label_2'].values```. Can I use your generator in that case? Plus my images are in the form of **Rank-4** matrices. ie a matrix of shape ```(rows,weight,height,1)``` for grayscale images and use the min ```flow()``` method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this seems to be to create a new generator class expanding the one provided by Keras that parses the data augmenting only the images and yielding all the outputs.

Comment: can you pleae share a code with the docstring? I have the code but I am unable to understand the workings.

Comment: [Here is the code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12639)